# Cannot find module 'react-lazily' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Getting this error while trying to use lazily.

Cannot find module 'react-lazily' or its corresponding type declarations.

Comment: Have you installed react-lazily first?

Comment: i imported it using import { lazily } from "react-lazily";

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `npm i react-lazily` in the terminal and try again.